# Why does Ubuntu delay a lot on booting?

Tags: bootchart

I have a problem. My Ubuntu delays a lot to boot, my computer is 4GB RAM, Core2Duo 3.2Ghz

This is my bootchart: http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/138/desktopmvx.png

I can't understand what is the problem. Thank you.

## Original question in spanish:

> Por que tarda tanto el arranque de ubuntu?
>
> Hola les comento que tengo un problema mi ubuntu tarda demasiado
>   arrancando, mi computadora es 4GB Ram, core2duo 3.2ghz
>
> Este es mi bootchart
>   http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/138/desktopmvx.png No entiendo cual
>   es el problema.
>
> Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reducing your start up applications, this may help.

Try :

**bootup-manager** (http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bum.html)

OR

**grub-customizer** (http://www.noobslab.com/2012/09/install-grub-customizer-30-in.html)

Comment: The problem its the time to boot, i use de tool Bum for diable some service that do not need, I change some service from init.d but the time its same, the boot time takes much :( thanks

Comment: in that case, you I can suggest you three options, 

1. Try booting in recovery mode (just to make sure if its problem of some driver loading or something else)

2. Check for loading of hard disks or drives in fstab

3. One solution I tried is use of multiple cores while booting to speed up the process (http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/concurrent-booting-make-full-use-of-your-multi-core-processors-during-boot-time/)
thanks.

Comment: How to use multiple cores in the booting? thanks! =D

Comment: http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/concurrent-booting-make-full-use-of-your-multi-core-processors-during-boot-time/ check this link